# Converting distinct values of a Spark dataframe column into a list

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
+-------+-----+----------+--------------+
| Name  | Age | Pet Name | Phone Number |
+-------+-----+----------+--------------+
| Brett |  14 | Rover    | 123 456 7889 |
| Amy   |  15 | Ginger   | 123 456 8888 |
| Amy   |  15 | Polly    | 123 456 8888 |
| Josh  |  14 | Fido     | 312 456 9999 |
+-------+-----+----------+--------------+
```

And I need to present it in the following format using Spark:

```
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------+
| Name  | Age |   Pet Name    | Phone Number |
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------+
| Brett |  14 | Rover         | 123 456 7889 |
| Amy   |  15 | Ginger, Polly | 123 456 8888 |
| Josh  |  14 | Fido          | 312 456 9999 |
+-------+-----+---------------+--------------+
```

Can someone please help me with the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use groupBy Name and Age and collect as list for Pet Name as below

```
df.groupBy("Name", "Age")
  .agg(collect_list($"Pet Name").as("PetName"), first("Phone Number").as("PhoneNumber"))
```

Or you could also do

```
data.groupBy("Name", "Age", "Phone Number")
  .agg(collect_list($"Pet Name").as("PetName"))
```

Output:

```
+-----+---+---------------+------------+
|Name |Age|PetName        |PhoneNumber |
+-----+---+---------------+------------+
|Amy  |15 |[Ginger, Polly]|123 456 8888|
|Brett|14 |[Rover]        |123 456 7889|
|Josh |14 |[Fido]         |312 456 9999|
+-----+---+---------------+------------+
```

If you need string you can use `concat_ws` as

```
data.groupBy("Name", "Age", "Phone Number")
  .agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list($"Pet Name")).as("PetName"))
```

Output:

```
+-----+---+------------+------------+
|Name |Age|Phone Number|PetName     |
+-----+---+------------+------------+
|Brett|14 |123 456 7889|Rover       |
|Amy  |15 |123 456 8888|Ginger,Polly|
|Josh |14 |312 456 9999|Fido        |
+-----+---+------------+------------+
```